# How to cache into disk audio streamed into MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, caching, streaming, media-player

How to cache into disk audio streamed into MediaPlayer? I'd like to use cached audio instead of downloading it each time. Unfortunately `setDataSource` even do not accepts `InputStream`, so I don't know solution.. My code:

```
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(/* file url */));
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it to the SDcard (or anywhere) and then play it back using the `public void setDataSource (String path)` method of MediaPlayer

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExtrnalStorageDirectory() + "/yoursoundfile.mp3");
```

you may have to tweak the path to get it correct.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. And it will be possible even play file simultaneously with it's download process?